# If $f(x) = -2\sin(x)$ then $f′(x)$ equals what?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f(x) = -2\sin(x)$ then $f′(x)$ equals what?

A: $2\cos x$

If $f(x) = (15)^x$ then $f′(x)$ = ?

A: $(15)^x \ln (15)^x$

Are my solutions correct?

Comment: I assume that the second question involves $15^x$?

Comment: No, your first solution is not correct, but it's close.

Comment: To do the second one, write $15^x=e^{x\ln(15)}$

Comment: yes it does @lulu. I corrected that

Comment: For a quick check on derivative problems, I suggest using [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+-2sin%28x%29). Link uses your example.

Comment: I got $ln(15)⋅15x$ Is that the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=-2\sin x\Rightarrow f'(x)=-2\sin'x=-2\cos x$

and

$f(x)=15^x\rightarrow f'(x)=15^x\ln15$

Answer (score 1):

For $f(x) = (15)^x$ then $f′(x)$?

---

For these type of question , I tend to rewrite it as such (If you are not confident in your ability to differentiate with x on the top as an exponent)

$$f(x) = (15)^x$$

$$ y = 15^x $$

$$ \ln(y) = \ln(15^x) $$

$$ \ln(y) = x\ln(15) $$

Now take the derivative on both sides with respect to x

$$ \frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = \ln(15) $$

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \ln(15) \cdot y $$

But $ y = 15^x $

$$ \therefore f'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} = \ln(15) \cdot 15^x $$